# Placing a list of data into a div from php in a loop

Tags: php, html, mysqli

this is building off a previous question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15534272/interpreting-the-day-of-a-datetime-and-putting-it-into-a-relevant-div

In essence I have this table:

```
Events Table
EventID | Start               | End                 |  Details
1       | 2013-03-18 09:00:00 | 2013-03-18 10:00:00 |  Event is in room 6
2       | 2013-03-18 10:00:00 | 2013-03-18 11:00:00 |  Event is in room 3
```

and this column:

```
<div class="timetable-column-first">
    <div class="timetable-row-start">Time</div>
    <div class="timetable-row">9:00am</div>
    <div class="timetable-row">10:00am</div>
</div>

<div class="timetable-column">
    <div class="timetable-row-start">Monday</div>
    <div class="timetable-row" id="mon-9"></div>
    <div class="timetable-row" id="mon-10"></div>
</div>
```

I have built this php query to fetch the information I need:

```
function getEvents($weekNumStart, $weekNumEnd){
    $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
    if (!$mysqli) {
        die('There was a problem connecting to the database.');
    }
    else {
        if ($weekNumEnd == '') {
            $weekNumEnd = $weekNumStart;
        }
        $query = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT EventID, DAYOFWEEK(Start) AS wday, Events.Start, HOUR(Start) AS sHour, HOUR(End) AS eHour, Events.End, Details, StartName FROM Events, Week WHERE StartName >= '$weekNumStart' AND StartName <= '$weekNumEnd' AND Events.Start >= StartWeek AND Events.Start <=EndWeek;");
        $query->execute();
        $query->bind_result($eventID, $dayofweek, $startDateTime, $startHour, $endHour, $endDateTime, $weekName);
        while ($query->fetch()){
            echo $eventID, $dayofweek, $startDateTime, $startHour, $endHour, $endDateTime, $weekName;
        }
    }
    $mysqli->close();
}
```

The problem is this query is done in an attached php file /functions.php which is included in the header.

I don't know how to change this line:

```
echo $eventID, $dayofweek, $startDateTime, $startHour, $endHour, $endDateTime, $weekName;
```

So that either it returns each array to the original index.php so that I can then use jquery to insert it into the columns and rows of my div ids. So that for example the details would end up like this in the divs:

```
<div class="timetable-column">
    <div class="timetable-row-start">Monday</div>
    <div class="timetable-row" id="mon-9">1 - Event is in room 6</div>
    <div class="timetable-row" id="mon-10">2 - Event is in room 3</div>
</div>
```

As it stands my function works, echoing back all the individual data from the server.

On the index.php page I just call it as this:

```
getEvents($weekNumStart, $weekNumEnd);
```

I thought about return array instead of echo, but wouldn't that just return the one lot of rows?
And so when I picked it up on the index.php page with list `($the data here) = getEvents($weekNumStart, $weekNumEnd);` I would only have the first event sent back?

Comment: Well you definitely didn't leave out any details :]

Comment: heh, I've been muddling over the problem for a while. I suppose my issue is, I can't seem to return multiple variables, in a loop, to then use that loop to display it in jquery. So I thought I'd come here and ask, but I worry it's a bit too nitty gritty for people to sit down to answer :(

Comment: I'm working on the answer...I accidentally posted it too early though, so it's not complete yet o.O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My typical model for doing things like this would be:

```
function getEvents($weekNumStart, $weekNumEnd){
    // I'm moving the SQL up here just so it's out of the way for a minute;
    $sql_str = "SELECT EventID, DAYOFWEEK(Start) AS wday, Events.Start, HOUR(Start) AS sHour, HOUR(End) AS eHour, Events.End, Details, StartName FROM Events, Week WHERE StartName >= '$weekNumStart' AND StartName <= '$weekNumEnd' AND Events.Start >= StartWeek AND Events.Start <=EndWeek";


    $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
    if (!$mysqli) {
        die('There was a problem connecting to the database.');
    }
    else {
        if ($weekNumEnd == '') {
            $weekNumEnd = $weekNumStart;
        }
        $query = $mysqli->prepare($sql_str); // I moved the string above just for clarity
        $query->execute();
        $query->bind_result($eventID, $dayofweek, $startDateTime, $startHour, $endHour, $endDateTime, $weekName);

        // LINE ADDED:
        $data_arr = array();
        while ($query->fetch()){
            // I'm creating an associative array to sort each result by day of
            // the week
            $data_arr[$dayofweek] = array(
                $eventID, $dayofweek, $startDateTime, 
                $startHour, $endHour, $endDateTime, $weekName
            );
            /* Example of what the object would look like with your events in it.
            ['Monday' => [[
                   1, "Monday", "2013-03-18 09:00:00", 
                   "09", "10", "2013-03-18 10:00:00",
                   "Event is in room 6"
            ], [
                   2, "Monday", "2013-03-18 10:00:00", 
                   "10", "11", "2013-03-18 11:00:00",
                   "Event is in room 3"
            ]]];
             */
        }
        $mysqli->close(); // a little redundant, but meh
        return $data_arr; // returns each of your results as an array within an array
    }
    $mysqli->close();
```

}

Then from wherever you are calling your getEvents() function, do something like this:

```
$data = getEvents($weekNumStart, $weekNumEnd);

$html = '';
$firstCol = '';
$secondCol = '';

// for each day in the data array:
foreach($data as $day) {
    $firstCol .= '<div class="timetable-column-first">'
           . '<div class="timetable-row-start">Time</div>';
    $secondCol .= '<div class="timetable-column">'
           . '<div class="timetable-row-start">' . $day . '</div>';

    $timeStartRow = '';
    $detailsRow = '';
    for($i = 0; $i < count($data[$day]); $i++) {
        $startHour = $data[$day][$i][3];
        $details = $data[$day][$i][6];

        // build the content rows within the first column
        $timeStartRow .= '<div class="timetable-row">' 
                      . $startHour                         // append each start hour
                      . '</div>';

        // build the content rows within the second column
        $detailsRow .= '<div class="timetable-row" id="' 
                    . $day . '-' . $starHour . '">'        // create the id
                    . $details                             // deats!
                    . '</div>';
    }
    $timeStartRow .= '</div>'; // close off .timetable-column-first
    $detailsRow .= '</div>'; // close off .timetable-column

    $html .= $firstCol . $timeStartRow . $secondCol . $detailsRow;
    $firstCol = '';
    $secondCol = '';
} 

echo $html; // I can't guarantee it will work, but it'll be 90% there :]
```

Hope this helped. If nothing else, scan it for the overall idea that I'm going for. Good luck!

Comment: Cheers for the help, I'll hang on and hold off commenting until you've had time to finish it, think I responded too early :)

Comment: No prob man. An equally long answer in keeping with the spirit of your long question :]

Comment: Awesome, I can work with this. Thanks for taking so much time to help out :)

Comment: No prob! Glad I could help to some extent. Cheers!